# Using power series, compute: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn)

I need to compute the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}$$
using power series.

Any hints of how should I do that?

Comment: @Jozef: Note that in the answers to the question linked by Didier you have $\sum nr^{n}$. Your question is a special case for $r=1/2$. (Other questions linked to that one might have answers interesting for you too.)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{0}^{\infty}x^n = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}x^n = \sum_{1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}$$ so $x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{1}^{\infty}nx^{n}$. Using $x = 1/2$ should give you what you want.

Comment: I recommend you to use double dollar sign to make it more readable. I can hardly follow the steps. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Gigili Better?

Comment: @Alex :Thanks for the answer. How do I explain the first equality in the second row?

Comment: The fundamental fact about power series is that for $|x|<1$, $\sum_{0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$. Since these two expressions are equal, their derivatives must be equal.

Comment: For interchanging sum and derivative: I think we can either use [uniform convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability), since power series converges uniformly for $|x|<r$, where $r$ is the [radius of convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence). Or - perhaps easier approach - we can consider the series as [formal power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Comment: I'm familiar with the proof by uniform convergence, but I recall in my calculus class when we were asked to do this sort of problem we were simply given that sum and derivative can be interchanged.

Comment: @Alex: Now it looks great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint. You know that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}x^n$. What if you differentiated both sides?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to compute $$S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{3}{2^3} + \cdots$$ 
Now consider $$ f(x)= \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2^2} + \frac{x^3}{2^3} + \cdots = \displaystyle\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{1 - \frac{x}{2}}$$ From here evaluate the value of $f'(1)$.